# What query whould I use to go through multiple levels of dependencies?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Following DBStructure:

```
App
   has_many :app_versions

AppVersion
  has_many :found_items
  has_many :items, through => :found_items

FoundItem
  belongs_to :app_version
  belongs_to :item

Item
   has_many :found_items
   has_many :app_versions, through => :found_items
```

I want to get all the `Apps` that include a `Item`.
I don't know how to query this scheme to get the results, since there are so many levels.

I can do it as follow:

```
apps = []
item.app_versions.each {|av| apps << av.app} => takes lots of database queries
apps.uniq!

updated version:
item.app_versions.find(:all, :include => :app).each {|av| apps << av.app} 
apps.uniq!
//Not so many queries
```

Someone a pointer?

Answer (score 0):

```
App.joins(:app_versions => :items).where(:items => { :id => item.id})
```

Comment: This does seem to work, but gives me more items then my example solution?

Comment: I am sorry, i meant apps indeed.